# Switching languages is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, language-switching

I want to switch between languages. I wrote a function in the controller. However, only the first switch works. Then I do not want to work.
Moreover, for each click magnifies the address for a link that leads to change the language:

```
contact/switchLanguage/switchLanguage/switchLanguage/en
```

Code in controller:

```
public function switchLanguage($language = "")
{
    if ($language == "pl")
    {
        $this->smarty->display('contact.tpl');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->smarty->display('contact_eng.tpl');
    }
}
```

Code in HTML:

```
<a href="switchLanguage/pl">Poland</a>
<a href="switchLanguage/en">English</a>
```

Comment: The is the problem? Question is not clear. Would you explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('switchLanguage/pl);?>">Poland</a>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('switchLanguage/en');?>">English</a>
```

or simply

```
<a href="/switchLanguage/pl">Poland</a>
<a href="/switchLanguage/en">English</a>
```